# spannable string gives different result on different devices

Tags: android, string, spannablestring

I am using SpannableStringBuilder to set a text on a textview but it is giving me different results on different devices.

Here is the code of spannableString builder

```
 SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        SpannableString first = new SpannableString("Directions to Send or Clear Alert:\n\n" +
                "Option 1 of 2: To Send Alert, click the \"");
        first.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, first.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        first.setSpan( new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0,  first.length()-27, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        SpannableString second = new SpannableString("Match / STOP!");
        second.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, second.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        SpannableString third = new SpannableString("\" button next to the matching person.\n" +
                "Option 2 of 2: To Clear Alert, you can choose either of these 2 options:\n");
        third.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, third.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        third.setSpan( new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 38,  53, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        SpannableString third1 = new SpannableString("A) Click any of the \"");
        third1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, third1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        third1.setSpan( new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0,  1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        SpannableString four = new SpannableString("No Match / CONTINUE");
        four.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#008000")), 0, four.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        SpannableString five = new SpannableString("\" buttons.\n" +
                "B) Click on the \"X\" (clear) button at the top right of this message screen.");
        five.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, five.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        five.setSpan( new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 11,  12, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        builder.append(first);
        builder.append(second);
        builder.append(third);
        builder.append(third1);
        builder.append(four);
        builder.append(five);

        headingTv.setText(builder);
```

On some devices text appears like this which is correct,

[image]

but in some devices like google pixel2 it appears like this which is horrible.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this that why it is happening?

Comment: Are you trying on google pixel2 emulator??

Comment: Ya I tried on emulator its fine, but at client's side its not wokring. second screenshot has been shared by client

Comment: yes. i have also tested the same and it is working emulator

Comment: any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: may be you should add a space after the "CONTINUE" and give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot

```
String first = "Directions to Send or Clear Alert:\n\n" + "Option 1 of 2: To Send Alert, click the \"";
String second = "Match / STOP!";
String third = "\" button next to the matching person.\n" + "Option 2 of 2: To Clear Alert, you can choose either of these 2 options:\n";
String third1 = "A) Click any of the \"";
String four = "No Match / CONTINUE";
String five = "\" buttons.\n" + "B) Click on the \"X\" (clear) button at the top right of this message screen.";


int blackColor = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.black);
Spanned third1Spanned = setSpanColor(third1, blackColor);
headingTv.setText(TextUtils.concat(
        first,
        " " ,
        second,
        " " ,
        third,
        " " ,
        third1Spanned,
        " " ,
        four,
        " " ,
        five));


public static Spanned setSpanColor(String s, int color) {
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
    ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, s.length(), 0);
    ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),0,s.length(),SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return ss;
}
```

Comment: @KartikaVij This is my one and only solution for changing color of a certain part of string

Answer (score 1):

I tried to read the starting and ending postion of string from complete statement and then set Color or font style to it.

```
    String completeStatement = "A) Click any of the No Match / CONTINUE";//complete statement /line
                String search = "No Match / CONTINUE";
    
   
    
                Pattern word = Pattern.compile(search);
    
                Matcher match = word.matcher(completeStatement);
                int start = -1;
                int end = -1;
    
                while (match.find()) {
                    start = match.start();
                    end = match.end();
                }
    
    
                SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(offerExpiredStatement);
                spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
                        start, end,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), start, end, 0);
                textView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
```

**Kotlin**

```
  val additionalAmountRequiredLabel: SpannedString = buildSpannedString {

            append("Additional ")

            bold {
                append("Rs.${mpiModel.additionalAmountRequired}")
            }
            append(" required")
        }
```